# Merged List from Sources and Prefixes

Tags: java

I have been given this below problem in school, I have solved as per my understanding and solution is as below. Can someone please help me to give a better solution for the same.

Question:

> Produce a software application that creates a filtered merging of two case-insensitive sorted lists. The first input list is designated as the Source list and the other as the Prefixes list. The application will produce a merged list containing items that come from the Source and Prefixes lists using the following algorithm:
>
> An item X is in the merged list if and only if one of the following is true:
>
> a) X is from the Source list and there is an item Y in the Prefixes list that is a case-insensitive string prefix for X.
>
> b) X is from the Prefixes list and there is no item in the Source list for which X is a case-insensitive string prefix.
>
> The completed merged list should be in the same sort order as the items in the original two lists.

My Solution:

```
public ArrayList<String> merge(List<String> srcList, List<String> preList) {
        // If Prefixes list is empty then there cannot be a new merge list
        if (preList.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        int sourcesListSize = srcList.size();
        int prefixesListSize = preList.size();
        ArrayList<String> mergeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Loop through Sources list until end of the list is reached
        //ASSUMPTION: Both SourceList and PrefixList are already sorted.
        while (i < sourcesListSize && j<prefixesListSize) {
            mergeList.add(preList.get(j).concat(srcList.get(i)));
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        // If Prefixes list still have items, then add it to mergeList
        while (j < prefixesListSize) {
            mergeList.add(preList.get(j));
            j++;
        }
        return mergeList;

    }
```

Input:

- Source list: `{"pple","ow","enver",pic,"ull"}`
- PrefixList: `{"a","c","d","e","f"}`

`MergeList={"apple",cow","denver","epic","full"}`

Is my understanding correct? Is there any best other solution?

Comment: How are you expected to know that the letters in PrefixList match with the SourceList?  Also, can you only use each prefix once?  If not, the word "cull", "dull" and "full" could be assembled from the PrefixList and SourceList.

Comment: Assuming your instructor hasn't given you some direction on how to validate a prefix-source pair, you'll need a word list.  You can find several [here](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/). Once you have one, you could, for instance, perform binary searches on the file, read the file into an `ArrayList` and perform binary searches on that, or read it into a `HashSet` and use the `contains` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is homework I'll try not to give too much away, but per the definition of [prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring#Prefix), here are some examples:

> "a" is a prefix of "Apple"
>
> "cow" is a prefix of "Cow"
>
> "g" is **not** a prefix of "Zoo"
>
> "col" is **not** a prefix of "cool"

Based on that, what will the MergeList be for the following? Hint: there will be items from both SourceList and PrefixList in the correct MergeList. Post your solution and I'll critique it. Once you understand how this part works, you'll have a much better idea of how to code the solution.

> SourceList : {"Apple","Pepper","Denver", "Garage", "Zoo"}
>
> PrefixList : {"a","d","pe","xylophone","e"}